# Which HTTP verb is appropriate for processing a file and returning a result?

Tags: web-services, rest, http

I'm creating a REST API with an endpoint that takes a file as input (e.g. an Excel file), extracts all the email addresses from the file, and returns a list of email addresses. What would be the most appropriate HTTP verb to use for this endpoint? Semantically, it seems like a `GET` is the best choice, but passing file data in a URL seems like a bad idea. A `POST` would be better for passing a file, but `POST` implies a database record will be created and that the operation is not idempotent (which it is).

I realize this is a nit-picky semantics question, but surely others will have the same question, so hopefully the answer will be useful.

Comment: One of the reasons I'm not a big fan of pure-REST services - not everything fits nicely into one of the categories.

Comment: How is this not an idempotent operation? If you supply the same input file multiple times, do you get a different list of email addresses back each time? If so, the part that varies hasn't been described in your question...

Comment: url's have a 2048 character limit, so it would be a little tricky to send an excel file in there. Also, don't send GET's with bodies, as it is semantically meaningless.

Comment: @JulianReschke It would only have to be base64-encoded if the file is passed in the URL. I've removed this part of my question so as not to distract from the real question.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That was a mistake in my post—I got the language backwards. This operation IS idempotent. I've fixed my question.

Comment: I'm tempted to say REST isn't a good choice because you don't store, get and manipulate data **stored on the server** but data you pass to it. That's why you're having this issue. But I can't strengthen this with links or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POST doesn't imply idempotency, nor does it imply creating a DB record.

It's true that it would be nice not to have to use POST for something that *is* idempotent and save, but right now, there isn't a better HTTP method for that.

Answer (score 2):

The discussion is a bit pedantic, but my 2c is `PUT`.  `PUT` is an idempotent verb, and implies that it will be operating only on the resource that is being `PUT`.  However, [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6) suggests that the server MUST send a 301 redirect to the result.

**From RFC 2616**

> The fundamental difference between the POST and PUT requests is reflected in the different meaning of the Request-URI. The URI in a POST request identifies the resource that will handle the enclosed entity. That resource might be a data-accepting process, a gateway to some other protocol, or a separate entity that accepts annotations. In contrast, the URI in a PUT request identifies the entity enclosed with the request -- the user agent knows what URI is intended and the server MUST NOT attempt to apply the request to some other resource. If the server desires that the request be applied to a different URI,
>
> it MUST send a 301 (Moved Permanently) response; the user agent MAY then make its own decision regarding whether or not to redirect the request.

Of course, as Julian pointed out so politely, RFC 2616 has been obsoleted by [RFC 2731](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) which makes no such requirement.

YMMV.  In reality, it seems to make sense to just do what makes sense to you.

Comment: "the RFC" is RFC 7231; neither it nor RFC 2616 say it needs to be 301.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, the spec you quoted suggests that using POST would be more appropriate: "That resource might be a data-accepting process".

Answer (score 0):

Don't get hung up on this. It is the sort of thing that won't matter once make a decision. Personally I'd stick POST for anything that doesn't fall within "CRUD" semantics. Heck, if you were designing a SOAP or WCF service you probably wouldn't be considering this decision and that is one reason I don't place much importance on designing to the RESTful model unless there is a specific requirement to do so in order to interop. Otherwise, I design a SOA with service contracts that make sense, with no thought about which transport verb it falls under.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key sentence in the PUT RFC is this:

```
A successful PUT of a given
representation would suggest that a subsequent GET on that same
target resource will result in an equivalent representation being
sent in a 200 (OK) response.
```

There is no such expectation in your use case scenario (unless users are expected to PUT to different url's for each different Excel and you save each response). It seems to fall well into the "data processing resource" described for POST in the same RFC.